# Creating three columns in SQL using the following information

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

I am trying to create a statement that combines the following into three columns, BusinessEntityID, AveQuota and PctComm. I am having trouble joining, I keep getting a syntax error near join.  Please help

```
SELECT BusinessEntityID, AVG (SalesQuota) as AveQuota
from [sales].[SalesPersonQuotaHistory]
group by BusinessEntityID 
join 
select (commissionpct * salesytd) as PctComm from sales.SalesPerson
```

The orginal question was to find each sales person's average Quote (from QuotaHistory, using aggregation) as a column called AvgQuota and join it with a column that calucalates the same sales person's commissions earnings YTD (from SalesPerson, uses two colums from a calculation).

Comment: Have you read any manaul or guide for how to construct mySQL queries? Can you please show us your table definitions

Comment: Honestly you need to review some basic SQL tutorials on how to join tables

Answer (score -1):

You are missing the information on which column to join those tables in the the 'join' syntax.
An example for join syntax:

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID, Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderDate
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Customers ON Orders.CustomerID=Customers.CustomerID;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).